# C# convert a long to string

Tags: c#

Here my problem is:

I have this code:

```
static long CountLinesInFile(string f)
{
    long count = 0;
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Which counts the lines of a text file. The problem I have is that when I'm trying this:

```
textBox1.Text = CountLinesInFile("test.txt");
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'string'
```

It seems legit, but how am I supposed to convert it to string? In Java its a simple `toString()`

Can someone give me a solution?

Comment: Yups you can try `.ToString()`

Comment: It's strange that you even know the method name in java, but you haven't looked if there's a similar method in C# (`toString() vs. ToString()`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiler Error Message: Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334347/compiler-error-message-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-long-to-string)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the `ToString()` method like this:

```
textBox1.Text = CountLinesInFile("test.txt").ToString();
```

Comment: An interesting detail worth mentioning is that `ToString` uses the `CurrentCulture` which might change based on the OS language. To get a consistent output the culture should be provided.

Answer (score 10):

> In Java its a simply .ToString

And in C#, its simply `.ToString()`.

Happy learning.

Answer (score 5):

just write

```
textBox1.Text =(CountLinesInFile("test.txt")).ToString();
```

[MSDN: Object.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx)  - Returns a string that represents the current object.

Answer (score 0):

try this `textBox1.Text = CountLinesInFile("test.txt").ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to convert long to string.

1. Using `.ToString()`

   long testField = 100;
   string stringEquivalent = testField.ToString();
2. Using `string.Format`

   long testField = 123;
   string stringEquivalent = string.Format("{0}", testField);
3. Using `Convert.ToString`

   long testField = 123;
   string stringEquivalent = Convert.ToString(testField);
4. Using `String interpolation`

   long testField = 123;
   string stringEquivalent = $"{testField}";
5. Using + operator

   long testField = 123;
   string stringEquivalent = "" + testField;
6. Using `StringBuilder`

   long testField = 123;
   string stringEquivalent = new StringBuilder().Append(testField).ToString();
7. Using `TypeConverter`

   TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(long));
   long testField = 123;
   string stringEquivalent = (string)converter.ConvertTo(testField, typeof(string));

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
long count = 12345;
string s = long.Parse(count, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or simply

```
string s = count.ToStringInvariant();
textBox1.Text = s;
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

champs.

I did this:
"Cast the dynamic value to long and convert to string"

```
((long)x.PersonId).ToString();
```

Comment: This is not an appropriate answer to this question. If you have a **different** question (related to `dynamic`) then please write it up, and answer it yourself there.

Comment: @mjwills ok i can write   ((long)CountLinesInFile("test.txt")).ToString()