# How to fix : " Cannot implicitly convert type to 'string' " error

Tags: c#, textbox, converters

I have a conversion problem with this code:

```cs
Convert.ToString(result)
hourA.Text = result;
```

The `result` word is a **DateTime** and I would like to convert it in text to put it in a TextBox

For me, this code looks like good but I still have the following error:

> CS0029  C# Cannot implicitly convert type to 'string'

What could I change to make it work?

Comment: Try result.ToString() and you can even change your output fomat like result.ToString("MM_dd_yy"); fe.

Comment: Can you use `result.ToString()`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiler Error Message: Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334347/compiler-error-message-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-long-to-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
hourA.Text = result.ToString("d");
```

to get short date time string representation,
if your result hold value like 10/24/2019 10:54:40 AM
the short text representation would be 10/24/2019,

there are too many string representation for datetime, all are listed in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

Convert datetime to string

```
DateTime date= DateTime.Now;
string result = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

append result string to textbox

```
hourA.Text = result ;
```

Comment: The result string is not appended to the `Text` property, it overwrites the value.